# PHP Sub-Directory

Tags: php, subdirectory

I have my php in `/srv/www/site` directory, which resolves to `www.domain.com/site`.

How can I pull out the `site/` to make a type of `BASE_URL`?

I would like do something like: `BASE_URL to == "http://www.domain.com/site"`.

I know how to `define`, that's not the problem. The problem is I want my script to be installed in any folder on a site, and know that its the base folder.

**Update**

This script would essentially be called in `http://www.anyonesdomain.com/any/possible/sub/directory/index.php` and, in that case, `BASE_URL` would be `http://www.anyonesdomain.com/any/possible/sub/directory`.

Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: What do you mean by `BASE_URL`?

Comment: it's essentially a site within a site. Like if you install wordpress at `www.domain.com/blog`, your `BASE_URL` for everything related to wordpress would be `http://www.domain.com/blog/`

Comment: Are you wanting requests to domain.com to resolve to domain.com/site? If so the answers are; mod_redirect, apache namevirtualhosts, redirects. Pick one :)

Comment: Strictly php, can't assume I'm using any specific apache, or yawn, or iis.

Comment: Lol why are you guys raging on the down vote? If you have a problem, leave a comment. If you don't understand the question, ask me to clarify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse out the **PHP_SELF** server variable, something like:

```
$SCRIPT_LOCATION = substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 0, strrpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], "/"));
```

Comment: Yeah that was from memory, so probably was't perfect. You're welcome.